# C# UNITY - loop of instantiating objects, some childs are referenced other not

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I should warn you that code is made by a newbie, I am learning the ropes and there is surely better way to make this in UNITY.
So i make a nested loop using x and y as variables, i instantiate some tiles and inside the tiles i created a child object to be rendered only if i click on the tile.
Seems everything fine except that the tiles with x>4 do not show child renderer when i click, they exist but do not show render. strange enough if i reduce the boardSizeY to 6 or less, all the x are working in the onClick script...
I am really confused and cannot find any reasonable answer, anyone can point me in the right direction?Here the two scripts "CaselleTerreno.cs" is a component of a game object

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class CaselleTerreno : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject tilePrefab;
    private int boardSizeX = 10;
    private int boardSizeY = 8;
    public float tileSize = 1f;
    public Sprite[] spriteSheet;
    public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    public int sliceIndex;
    public GameObject activeChild;
    public GameObject RightPane;
    public TextMeshProUGUI rightText;

    public GameObject overTileObject;
    private SpriteRenderer overTileObjectSpriteRenderer;
    private float randRange;
    private int OnTileObject;
    public static class MyConstants
    {
        public static readonly string[,] DATA = {
        {"31", " spreaded remains",         "0", "0", "0", "0"},
        {"32", "  inhanimate creature",     "10", "20", "30", "40"},
        {"33", "n empty space",             "0", "0", "0", "0"},
        {"34", " dead creature",             "10", "20", "30", "40"},
        {"35", " metallic container",       "11", "21", "31", "41"},
        {"36", " dead bush",                "12", "22", "32", "42"},
        {"37", " abandoned metal object",   "13", "23", "33", "43"},
        {"38", "n half open trapdoor",      "14", "24", "34", "44"},
        {"39", " cocoon of a giant insect", "15", "25", "35", "45"},
        {"40", " strange hard box",         "16", "26", "36", "46"},
        {"41", " strange vial",             "17", "27", "37", "47"},
        {"42", " giant boulder",            "18", "28", "38", "48"},
        {"43", " tuft of grass",            "19", "29", "39", "49"},
        {"44", " bizzarre succulent",       "10", "20", "30", "40"},
        {"45", " skeletal remain",          "11", "21", "31", "41"},
        {"46", " colony of arthropods",     "12", "22", "32", "42"},
        {"47", " packet",                   "13", "23", "33", "43"},
        {"48", " plant",                    "14", "24", "34", "44"},
        {"49", " bush with colorful berries", "15", "25", "35", "45"},
        {"50", " fruit tree",               "16", "26", "36", "46"},
        {"51", " lively tree",              "17", "27", "37", "47"},
        {"52", " dry tree",                 "18", "28", "38", "48"}
    };
    }

    void Start()
    {
        spriteSheet = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("TilesAtlasTerrain3");
        RightPane = GameObject.Find("RightPane");
        rightText = RightPane.transform.Find("Canvas/RightText").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();


        // Loop through the rows and columns of the chessboard
        /*for (int x = 0; x < boardSizeX; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < boardSizeY; y++)
            {*/
        for (int x = 0; x < boardSizeX; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < boardSizeY; y++)
            {
                randRange = Random.Range(0, 4) * 90f;
                GameObject tile = Instantiate(tilePrefab, new Vector3(x * tileSize, y * tileSize, 0), Quaternion.identity);
                tile.name = "Tile " + x + "_" + y;
                tile.transform.parent = transform;
                tile.GetComponent<TerrainTileScript>().rightText = rightText;
                activeChild = tile.transform.Find("SelectedRenderLayer").gameObject;
                activeChild.SetActive(false);
                spriteRenderer = tile.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
                if (Random.Range(0, 100) < 85){   
                    sliceIndex = 0;               }
                else {
                    sliceIndex = Random.Range(0, 30);
                }
                spriteRenderer.sprite = spriteSheet[sliceIndex];
                spriteRenderer.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, randRange, Space.Self);

                // (Random.Range(0f, 1f) < 0.075f)
                if (Random.Range(0f, 1f) < 0.725f)
                {
                    OnTileObject = Random.Range(34, 53);
                } 
                else
                {
                    OnTileObject = 33;
                }
                overTileObject = tile.transform.Find("OverTileObject").gameObject;
                overTileObjectSpriteRenderer = overTileObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
                overTileObjectSpriteRenderer.sprite = spriteSheet[OnTileObject];
                overTileObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, 360f - randRange, Space.Self);

                //OnTileObject data to store in vars of terraintile script
                tile.GetComponent<TerrainTileScript>().descOnTileObj = MyConstants.DATA[OnTileObject -31, 1];
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and "TerrainTilesScript.cs" is from the Asset TerrainTile

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class TerrainTileScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI rightText;
    public string descOnTileObj;


    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        //rightText.text = "Clicked tile: " + name;
        rightText.text = "Clicked tile: " + name+ "\n";
        

        CaselleTerreno caselleTerreno = GetComponentInParent<CaselleTerreno>();
        GameObject activeChild = caselleTerreno.activeChild;
        if (activeChild != null)
        {
            activeChild.SetActive(false);
        }
        activeChild = transform.Find("SelectedRenderLayer").gameObject;
        activeChild.SetActive(true);
        caselleTerreno.activeChild = activeChild;

        GameObject OverActiveChild = transform.Find("OverTileObject").gameObject;
        SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer = OverActiveChild.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        if (spriteRenderer != null)
        {
            string spriteName = spriteRenderer.sprite.name;
            string indexString = spriteName.Substring(spriteName.Length - 2, 2);
            //Debug.Log("The sprite name is: " + indexString);
            rightText.text += "(contiene " + indexString + ")\n";
            rightText.text += "There is a" + descOnTileObj + " here.\n";

        }
    }
}
```

Already verified where are y and x used and modified and removed chunks of code to see where is the bug...No clue still to find the bug

Comment: There could be an invisible collider or UI element in the way that catches the mouse click.

Comment: I verified, and i will verify again. But if i invert the for loops starting with y and then with x, I lose the reference of the right part of the board, instead than the top part... and i dont create UI or colliders, other than the tiles, in the loop

Comment: I have tested your scripts and I do not encounter any issue. I can use any gird size and the text is displayed correctly. Only thing I changed is that I don't use a sprite atlas, since I can't be bothered to make one with 50 elements and it only modifies the pictures. I can tell with certainty that this isn't a code related problem, but rather a configuration problem. You should supplement the question with information about your prefab and other relevant bits.

Comment: thank you very much to address me to new way to approach the issue. i will test on that

Comment: In fact if i now replace 
                 spriteRenderer.sprite = spriteSheet[sliceIndex];
with a more simple
                spriteRenderer.sprite = tempSprite;
i do not have error, 
 i will test on that direction... thanks again